# How to get new .plist data

Tags: ios, plist

I'm using this code to read data from a local (in the XCode project) .plist file.

```
NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GameData.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GameData" ofType:@"plist"];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
    }

    gameData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

And it worked great the start, but now I find when I step through the code in the simulator that my game is using a version of the .plist file that existed right at the start, and the new fields I've set up in my new GameData.plist file is not appearing.

I presume that's because it doesn't get the data again if the file already exists? but then how do I get the new version of the .plist file? I tried removing the if statement, but I get a runtime error saying the file already exists.

Comment: Check the return value of `copyItemAtPath:error:`. If it returns `NO`, log `error`.

Comment: I'll leave out the entire string, but it contains this "Cocoa error 516." and "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists", this is displayed at the copyItemAtPath line.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You check if it exists and only attempt to copy if it doesn't exist. So you shouldn't be getting an error about the file existing.

Comment: @rmaddy, the last line in the Q says OP tried without the if so I guess that's where the error is from.

Comment: Oops - didn't read the last paragraph, just the code. You need the `if` check shown in your posted code.

Comment: with the IF check, it obviously finds the file and then runs the last line, but somehow it's giving me the old .plist file, not the new one that I'm looking at right now in my XCode project, it's like it's grabbing a cached version?

Comment: That's correct behavior. You have no logic to say "if the version in the resource bundle has been updated, overwrite the copy in the Documents folder". Your logic is written to only use the version in the resource bundle if there is nothing in the Documents folder.

Comment: But doesn't this just read it from the documents folder ? gameData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; because if so it doesn't work, I still end up with the old version

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to setup a version system. But, the only reason to copy a file from the bundle to the documents folder is so you can edit it, so you need to think about how to merge the updated file in the bundle and the users additions in the documents folder.

Once you have a plan for merging the files, then you can change your `if` statement so it doesn't just check if the file already exists (if it does, you need to delete it before you can replace it) but also considers the version. You may want to store the currently copied version number in user defaults and add a version number to the file in the bundle. You may also want to keep the user modified data in a different file and use that as overrides.

Comment: Thanks, but all I'm trying to do is grab the data from the .plist file to set my game up, that's all, of course I alter the .plist data from time to time and I need the game just to load the new updated .plist file, that's all :)

Comment: But doesn't this read it from the docs folder? gameData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; ? because if so it doesn't work, I still end up with the old version.

Comment: Step back. Why do you have 2 versions? Don't copy the file to the doc folder.